# Is there a way to use Jackson's SerializationFeature with annotations

Tags: json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm trying to use `SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_CHAR_ARRAYS_AS_JSON_ARRAYS` but I'm not configuring the mapper myself, relying on annotations exclusively and letting Spring's RestTemplate (de)serialize automatically. Is there a way to enable the aforementioned feature in this scenario (i.e. annotations only)?

**NOTE:** I'm using Jackson 1.x and can't upgrade due to other libs...

Comment: Later Spring versions have upgraded to Jackson 2.x, so is it just because you can not upgrade Spring version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

checkout this link: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html

Example:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class,
    as=MySubClass.class,
    include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL,
    typing=JsonSerialize.Typing.STATIC
  )
```

Comment: You saying the way would be to provide my own (de)serializer that uses the features I want, right?

Comment: @kaqqao i'm afraid so, or there may some implementation you can use

Answer (score 3):

With JAX-RS (like DropWizard) you can actually annotated resource endpoints, using `@JacksonFeatures`

```
public class Resource {
      @Path("item")
      @GET
      @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable={ SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE })
      public Pojo getItem(String id) {
          ...
      }
}
```

I don't know if Spring exposes similar functionality, but it seems possible it does. And if not, it is something they should be able to add to allow per-endpoint setting/clearing of `SerializationFeature`s / `DeserializationFeature`s. So if it is not available, maybe file a feature request for Spring project?

Comment: Seems the @JacksonFeatures annotation isn't available in Jackson 1.x. Sorry I didn't specify the version to begin with, I updated the question now...

Comment: Correct, it is a later addition, Jackson 2.4 or so.